# Problem in filter column in dataframe by contain function in str by "|" operator

Tags: python, dataframe

Why is not filter the df like in the screenshot
[Show the function of str.contain("|") that's didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1dUB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `regex` parameter of `contains` to `False`.  In your code now, the string `"|"`  is parsed as a regular expression, but you want to match the literal pipe character.

```
movies_with_more_dir = movies_df[movies_df['director'].str.contains("|", regex=False)]
```